# How to create a mirror chart of area chart D3 js?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have created a area chart with D3 js in Angular 8.
[image: area chart]

D3 js configuration used:

```
data = [
    { x: 'TC11', y: 2, },
    { x: 'TC10', y: 3, },
    { x: 'TC9', y: 2, },
    { x: 'TC8', y: 1.5, },
    { x: 'TC7', y: 2, },
    { x: 'TC6', y: 2, },
    { x: 'TC5', y: 3, },
    { x: 'TC4', y: 1, },
    { x: 'TC3', y: 2, },
    { x: 'TC2', y: 1.5, },
    { x: 'TC1', y: 2, },
  ];
  margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
  width = 675 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  height = 100 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
  svg;

this.svg = d3.select("svg#area")
      .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
      .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",  "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
      

      var x = d3.scalePoint()
      .domain(["TC11", "TC10", "TC9", "TC8", "TC7", "TC6", "TC5", "TC4", "TC3", "TC2", "TC1"])  
      .range([0, this.width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function (d) { return d.y; })])
      .range([this.height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    // var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    var area = d3.area()
      .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.x); })
      .y0(this.height)
      .y1(function (d: any) { return y(d.y); });

    this.svg.append("path")
      .datum(this.data)
      .style("fill", "#D04242")
      .attr("d", area);

    this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
```

I need to create a exact mirror chart of this wrt X-axis and need to show that mirror chart on top of already existing one.

something like this:
[image]

I have tried this to create a mirror image:

```
 d3.select("svg#area")
    .attr("transform", "rotateX(180deg)");
```

But its not working. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses D3 to draw two different charts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>

      // set up

      const margin = { top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20 };

      const width = 675 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


      // create different groups for the top and bottom chart

      const paddingBetweenCharts = 20;
      const chartHeight = (height / 2) - paddingBetweenCharts;

      const topChart = svg.append('g');
      const bottomChart = svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(0,${(height / 2) + paddingBetweenCharts})`);

      // data

      const data = [
        { x: 'TC11', y: 2, },
        { x: 'TC10', y: 3, },
        { x: 'TC9', y: 2, },
        { x: 'TC8', y: 1.5, },
        { x: 'TC7', y: 2, },
        { x: 'TC6', y: 2, },
        { x: 'TC5', y: 3, },
        { x: 'TC4', y: 1, },
        { x: 'TC3', y: 2, },
        { x: 'TC2', y: 1.5, },
        { x: 'TC1', y: 2, },
      ];

      // scales

      const x = d3.scalePoint()
          .domain(["TC11", "TC10", "TC9", "TC8", "TC7", "TC6", "TC5", "TC4", "TC3", "TC2", "TC1"])
          .range([0, width]);

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, d =>  d.y)])
          .range([chartHeight, 0]);

      // mirror y scale by flipping range
      const yMirrored = y.copy().range([0, chartHeight]);


      // axis generators

      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
      const xAxisMirrored = d3.axisTop(x);


      // area generators

      const area = d3.area()
          .x(d => x(d.x))
          .y0(y(0))
          .y1(d => y(d.y));

      const areaMirrored = d3.area()
          .x(d => x(d.x))
          .y0(d => yMirrored(d.y))
          .y1(yMirrored(0));


      // top chart

      topChart.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .style("fill", "#D04242")
          .attr("d", areaMirrored);

      topChart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .call(xAxisMirrored);


     // bottom chart
      
      bottomChart.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .style("fill", "#D04242")
          .attr("d", area);

      bottomChart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", `translate(0,${chartHeight})`)
          .call(xAxis);
    </script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```